# How do i run a Python script in a Google Workflow?

Tags: google-workflows

How do i run a Python script in a Google Workflow? I can't find any examples. Lots about the reverse ie Python running/creating workflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Workflows is not for running language scripts like Python. It is designed for users to create a workflow that executes stuff in a certain way and order. If you want to run some Python scripts, you could consider [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/overview).

​

Answer (score 1):

Google Workflows allows you to run any container, [create-run-basic-job](https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/create-run-basic-job#gcloud), that means the container could be running anything that can be built in a container.

I do have a scenario where I do exactly that, after you have built your container with Python code, you can push it to [artifact-registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry) and then use the container image URI in the container job workflow config:

```
{
    "taskGroups": [
        {
            "taskSpec": {
                "runnables": [
                    {
                        "container": {
                            "imageUri": "gcr.io/google-containers/busybox",
                            "entrypoint": "/bin/sh",
                            "commands": [
                                "-c",
                                "echo Hello world! This is task ${BATCH_TASK_INDEX}. This job has a total of ${BATCH_TASK_COUNT} tasks."
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "computeResource": {
                    "cpuMilli": 2000,
                    "memoryMib": 16
                },
                "maxRetryCount": 2,
                "maxRunDuration": "3600s"
            },
            "taskCount": 4,
            "parallelism": 2
        }
    ],
    "allocationPolicy": {
        "instances": [
            {
                "policy": { "machineType": "e2-standard-4" }
            }
        ]
    },
    "labels": {
        "department": "finance",
        "env": "testing"
    },
    "logsPolicy": {
        "destination": "CLOUD_LOGGING"
    }
}
```

the above sample has a "/bin/sh" entrypoint, you can override the container entrypoint, or have it set already calling your Python code as long as the container image has Python set up.